# How to transmit password securely if you don't have https (ssl)?

Tags: http, ssl, https, security, password-protection

How to transmit password securely if you don't have https (ssl)?

Comment: Also elaborate why you cannot have https.

Comment: I cannot have ssl because it is too expensive. (http://tophost.bg/?page=services)

Comment: Use OpenID or OAuth instead of accepting passwords yourself if you cannot afford SSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digest authentication offers **some** protection, especially if you've a nice short nonce lifetime, and is easy to implement. This makes it appropriate in some cases where the password is the only thing you need to protect from snooping. See RFC 2617 for more.

It still isn't as secure as HTTPS though.

Comment: Well used digest authentication protects the password transmission pretty well but makes cleartext storage of the password on the server mandatory, pretty much an horrible thing should that password database be compromised, considering people tendencies to reuse usernames and passwords...

Comment: @Bruno, that's not true at all. You only need to store the MD5 of username + ":" + domain + ":" + password, and the domain is set by you (and so shouldn't match the same MD5 stored in another system). It's this digest that serves as a shared-secret, which is then digested again with the nonce on transmission. Obtaining this would allow people to access the system in question, but not given them the raw user/pass.

Comment: Yeah I was wrong, the password can be stored in a non reversible way, still one of the most dangerous ways to store passwords.

Answer (score 2):

The [Secure Remote Password](http://srp.stanford.edu/) protocol is designed exactly for those cases. There are JavaScript implementations floating around that should be suitable in a HTTP context. But keep in mind this can protect from someone **listening** passively but not from someone **meddling** with the traffic as they could just send your users corrupt JavaScript instead.

Also keep in mind that even if the client passwords can't be compromised one they are authenticated they'll still be vulnerable to a man in the middle attack unless you take care of protecting them, e.g. using [SRP Hermetic](http://www.denksoft.com/wordpress/web-development/secure-ajax-channel-srp-hermetic/)

[Clipperz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipperz/) should be a good JavaScript SRP library suitable for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is definitely recommended and there are several cheap (or free) sources to get SSL certificates. However, you can use a JavaScript encryption library like http://www.jcryption.org/ if you absolutely can't use SSL. Just remember:

> jCryption at it’s current state is no
>   replacement for SSL, because there is
>   no authentication, but the main goal
>   of jCryption should be a very easy and
>   fast to install plugin which offers a
>   base level of security.